# Stop handler after closing and open the applicaiton in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to stop Handler, after closing and then open the application again, but I don't know how, so can someone explain me, what I have to do in this situation?
I have the following method.

```
private Handler handler = new Handler();  
private Timer timer = new Timer(); 
private TimerTask timerTask;

private void openHandler(){
     timerTask = new TimerTask() {
         public void run() { 
            handler.post(myRunnable = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                            doSomething();                                                                                                                                                      

                }           
            });                                 
         }       
     };             
     timer.schedule(timerTask, min*60000);                                          
     dialog.dismiss();                                                   
     btnToggleTimer.setClickable(true); 
}
```

I call this method from a toggleButton:

```
btnToggleTimer.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

      public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked1) {  

                     btnToggleTimer.setClickable(false)

                      if(isCheked1){

                               openHandler();
                 }
              }
         });
```

The handler will stop, for example after 5 minutes, but if I want to stop it before this 5 minutes, after closing my app and open it again, What can I do about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think there is many ways to accomplish that.

I think I would stop the timer in `onDestroy()` of the Activiy (if I understand the question correctly)

Handler has a `removeCallbacks(Runnable r)` method so you could do:

```
handler.removeCallbacks(myRunnable);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

Or you could stop the TimerTask using `cancel()`

```
timerTask.cancel();
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html

Comment: Hello cYrixmorten, but the problem I think is that, when I close and open my app, new Timer, TimerTask and Handler will be created, and timerTask will trow exception.

Comment: If they are created in `onCreate` then the objects should be valid in `onDestroy`?